# how to get route template's ID using HttpContext?

Tags: asp.net

How to get route template's ID using HttpContext? Let's say in this case we want id (will be '10' in this case) from `Home/Index/10`. I have problem in my AuthorizationRequirementHandler, I need to access resource id from URL.

Comment: kindly share the code with us what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you have the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing package it should be there by default for MVC.

Then just use [GetRouteValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.routinghttpcontextextensions.getroutevalue?view=aspnetcore-2.2) extension method.

In your example:

```
// Home/Index/10
HttpContext.GetRouteValue("id"); // returns 10
```